# Hiding Javascript When Building a Widget

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, widget

I am building a web widget which will be very easy to integrate. Say `http://www.bicycleseller.com/` wants to integrate my widget on his web page. All he has to do is copy and paste the following to the head section of his page:

```
<script src="http://www.widgetprovider.com/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
Widget.create("123456accessKeyOfBicycleSeller").render("myWidget");
</script>
```

and `<div id="myWidget"></div>` to anywhere in the body section. The widget will be displayed in that div.

I, as the widget provider, host the **widget.js**:

```
var Widget = new function () {

    this.url = "www.widgetprovider.com/widget.jsp";
    this.name = "";
    this.parameters = "width=400,height=200,screenX=750,screenY=300,resizable=0";


    this.create = function (accessKey) {
        this.accessKey = accessKey;
        return this;
    };


    this.render = function (divId) {
        // make sure the document is fully loaded and place the widget on BicycleSellers page.
        // when the widget (a jpeg) is clicked, a jsp page I host will popup.
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = '<img src="images/widget-image.jpg" onclick="Widget.display()"/>';
        };
        return this;
    };

    this.display = function () {
        // open a popup window that displays a page I host.
        var popup = window.open(this.url + "?accessKey=" + this.accessKey, this.name, this.parameters);
        popup.focus();
        return this;
    };
};
```

So, the BicycleSeller places the widget on his page and when his users click on it, a popup appears that show them content from a page I host.
However, each webmaster that wants to embed my widget, has to provide an `accessKey`, unique to them, because the popup's content will be dependent on that.

My questions are:

**1)** In this scenario, anyone who goes to `bicycleseller.com` and views the HTML source can see his `accessKey` which is hard-coded in the head section. Then they can just navigate to `www.widgetprovider.com/widget.jsp?accessKey=123456`. I don't want that to happen. What can be done about this? For instance; I was looking at the source of Facebook and they seem to hide everything very well.

**2)** Is this a good way to go on building a widget? I was thinking of a lightbox rather than a popup window (which might be blocked by a popup blocker - although in this example it does not). Any comments/suggestions welcome.

**3)** If I try to place to widgets and write `Widget.create("key1").render("div1"); Widget.create("key2").render("div2");` two images are generated. But when clicked, both popups display `key1` s information. This is because the `Widget` class in `widget.js` is singleton. If I don't make it singleton, then I can't place the image's `onclick` attribute (`Widget.display()`). What do I do for that?

Looking for help on the three questions. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - The popup displays a JSP page. As one might propose a solution including JSP/Servlet/etc., I added the Java tag.

Comment: JGWeissman's answer fixes the problem with the 3rd question. But I am still looking for more answers on the first and second... Why is this question not getting more views with such popular tags and a straight-forward problem?

Comment: Put in a comment tag that asks them very nicely not to look at the code.

It's entirely foolish and unreasonable to ever think you can send data to someone and expect them not to have it.

Even with entirely trivial-to-overcome nonsense like checking "referer" headers, it simply doesn't matter. You've already sent the data, it's gone, it's out the door and at your user's system.

If there's a reason your users cannot look at the code then your system is fundamentally flawed and you need to change it.

Comment: @Incognito Why not just try and be a little nicer when commenting? Although I feel you might be of some help, I must say I really dislike your attitude.

Comment: As for what the wiseacre says, I don't expect to "send data and expect them not to have it." Nor I claim that "the users cannot look at the code." **First thing I want to accomplish is to make sure the widget (popup) can only work correctly from the website I gave permission to. So that only websites with valid `merchantId`s can host it and make it work correctly.** So that the link displayed in the popup doesn't get spammed. **And secondly, I'm looking for suggestions on building a widget; whether what I described is a good way to go or not.** Just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server can validate the "Referer" header of the request. This would stop casual users from viewing the popup content out of context by entering the URL in the address bar, or by following a third party link. Headers can be spoofed, but this takes some effort and is not a standard browser feature.

You will not be able to stop a hacker from loading the popup out of context on their own computer.

On the issue of popups being a good idea, I think something inline would be better, but also more work and less portable, so you have to decide if popups are good enough.

To make Widget not be a singleton, instead of:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = '<img src="images/widget-image.jpg" onclick="Widget.display()"/>';
});
```

use:

```
var widget = this;
$(window).load(function () {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src="images/widget-image.jpg";
    image.onclick = function() { widget.display() };
    document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(image);
});
```

By setting `onclick` to an actual function instead of the code for a function, you can refer back to the instance of Widget through the closure.

Comment: But the popup is opened from widget.js, which is hosted by me. Wouldn't the `Referrer` header point to my web address, instead of BicycleSeller's?

Comment: @Murat I would expect "Referer" to be the url of the page, not the javascript file, that originated the request. Your script causes BicycleSeller's page to open your URL with it's own URL as the "Referer".

Comment: Thank you, it seems like your solution is gonna work. Anything you can suggest for my second and third questions?

Comment: @Murat Edited with answers to those questions.

Comment: Regarding your answer to **3)**, `this` inside the callback will not refer to the same object as `this` outside it did. See [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Loether/XBhwL/).

Comment: Regarding your answer to **2)**, what do you mean by `something inline`? Can you please tell a bit more? More work is ok. Can `less portable` be eliminated with even more work? :)

Comment: @Murat by "inline" I mean loading the content into the same window. "Less portable" mostly refers to fitting in the style of of the host page. I don't really have any deep insights on that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be pointed to the fact that your widget - which is javascript based - can be cached and (even when not cached) the client is able to view the source. After all, javascript is executed on the client computer, not your server.

To "hide" things like you want to do it, you have to take care to let the "sensitive data" to be handled by server side scripts. Everything a client can download, can be viewed and messed with by clients. The only thing they can't get to is the stuff going on "behind the screens" at your server. So if you want to hide anything, keep it at your server.

The only safety level you can get with javascript is "obfuscation". But that's a safety level that can be lifted by almost anyone who invests a bit of time. (Read: script kids will love reversing stuff like that for the fun of it!)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I think @JGWeissman has given a possible solution.

In answer to your second question, I don't believe that a user initiated click to open a popup will be stopped by a popup blocker.  I believe the blockers are looking for code that runs regardless of what actions a user takes on the page.   It's fairly easy to make your own lightbox like popup, but might not be worth the time, especially since you aren't in control of the page you are being embedded on.  They could have Flash embedded in a way not compatible with lightbox type popup solutions which may cause you headaches.

In answer to your third question,  I'd make it so each time you "create" a widget, you actually create an object that represents it.  You can track those widget "instances" in your Widget object in an array.  You can also instantiate on window.onload method that loops through the "instances" and gives each on click method that will fire the instances accessKey. I'd also get rid of the separation between create and render since you seem to call them together.  So here is one way to do that:

```
var Widget = new function () {
        var widgets = [];
        this.url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        this.name = "";
        this.parameters = "width=400,height=200,screenX=750,screenY=300,resizable=0";

        window.onload = function () {
            var w;
            for (w = 0; w < widgets.length; w++) {
                document.getElementById(widgets[w].id).innerHTML = '<img src="images/widget-image.jpg" onclick="Widget.display(' + w + ')"/>';
            }
        };

        this.display = function (index) {
            widgets[index].display();//display the widget instance corresponding to the index
        }

        this.create = function (accessKey, elId) {
            var newWidget = {
                accessKey: accessKey,
                id: elId,
                display: function () {
                    // open a popup window that displays a page I host.
                    var popup = window.open(Widget.url + "?accessKey=" + accessKey, Widget.name, Widget.parameters);
                    popup.focus();
                }
            };

            widgets.push(newWidget);

            return newWidget;
        };


    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about 2 and 3 but I can answer 1.

What you can **not** do: prevent people from looking at your source code. Everything can be spoofed, you may stop casual users, but you wont stall a determined person for more than a few seconds (yes, seconds). What you *can* do is prevent people from using your code on their site.

You can make links that invalidate themselves after a grace period that you control. Example:

```
$key = "client_key";
$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$hash = md5("nonce" . $key . $time);    // super secret method than no one should ever find out
return return "hash=" . $hash . "&key=" . $key . "&time=" . $time;
```

This does require you to place server-side code on the website of your customer. The hash ensures no one can 'mess' with the variables because no one knows the method you're using for hashing (pick something a bit more obscure though, add a proper nonce). The `time` variable you can use to reject requests with a very old `time` value, say: 24 hours.

Still, you can't stop people from fetching the code once and keep a local copy of it for themselves, but at least you've excluded them from updates and bug fixes.

You could also add obfuscation so they can't easily *modify* or *maintain* the code.

There is just no way to completely prevent people from 'stealing' your JavaScript.